# Locating the number after the decimal point in Python

Tags: python

How can you find the number after decimal like this: 123.44 first number in decimal part which is 4. How can I find that in python?

Comment: I have tried frac and whole function , but that wan't help full at all!

Answer (score 8):

Easiest method, convert the number to `str` and then `split` based on `'.'`. I have put up each iteration below.

```
>>> num=123.44

>>> str(num).split('.')
=> ['123', '44']

>>> str(num).split('.')[1]
=> '44'

>>> str(num).split('.')[1][0]
=> '4' 

>>> int(str(num).split('.')[1][0])
=> 4
```

**NOTE :** Here, if the number is does not have decimal point, this will throw `Error`. So, you can check if it is present by doing:

```
>>> str(num).find('.')              #num=123.44
3
>>> str(num).find('.')              #num=123
-1
```

So, the `if` condition is :

```
>>> if str(num).find('.') >= 0 :
       #has decimal point
```

**Or**, just use `try/except`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! However, does that method work for large numbers like 123.444455?

Comment: Yes, for any large number. No limits.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be probably to multiply by 10, then convert to integer and do the modulo 10 operation:

```
int(number * 10) % 10
```

Comment: This is the most efficient and simplest method amongst the answers here (constant time FTW!). But, of course, we should check if a number has a decimal point or not. Otherwise, it would give out the wrong result.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais If number does not have decimal point or first decimal point is 0, it will return 0.

Comment: That is why we should check first if a number has a decimal or not. Since numbers with decimal points are usually `float`s or `double`s, we could just check the data type of a variable containing the number to see if it has a decimal point or not. But if the data type is a string, we could just typecast it to a `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 1):

A short way to do this that does not throw an error and works with negative numbers is the below code. It also doesn’t require you to import any libraries:

```
after_point = num - int(num)
10*round(after_point, 1)
```

This way you’ll get `0` if there is nothing after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not involve splitting a string. This one uses a `for` loop instead.

```
num = 123.44
after_dec_num = -1
has_seen_point = False
for digit in str(num):
    if digit == '.':
        has_seen_point = True
    elif has_seen_point:
        after_dec_num = int(digit)
        break

print(after_dec_num)
```

Once a digit after the decimal point is found, we would get that digit and the loop will stop. If the number does not have a decimal point, we would get `-1` instead.

An alternative would look like the one below.

```
num = 123.44
after_dec_num = -1
number = str(num)
for idx in range(len(number)):
    if number[idx] == '.':
        # Since we have a decimal point, we can always assume
        # that there would be a number after it.
        after_dec_num = int(number[idx + 1])
        break
```

This one uses indexes to be able to retrieve the succeeding digits easily. The results would be the with the preceding loop.